# How to set up a PHP CRON job in cPanel?

Tags: php, cron

I have added cronjob in cpanel to send a sms using textloal in php. It works perfectly outside the  cronjob. After running it in a cronjob it is not sending any sms.

This is my code

```php
<?php 
include('dbc.php');

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require('php-in/textlocal.class.php');
//require('php-in\Textlocal.class.php');

//require('consultantnext.com/danceschool/php-in/Textlocal.class.php');
$sql="SELECT * 
    FROM admin t1, batchinfo t2
    WHERE t1.batchname= t2.batchname  
    AND   t1.branchname= t2.branchname";

$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql)
or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        //echo   $row['mobile'];
        $mobile=$row['mobile'];
        $time=$row['time'];
        //echo $time;
        $numbers=(explode(" ",$mobile));
        foreach ($numbers as $item) {
            echo $item;
        }

        $Textlocal = new Textlocal(false, false, 'e34FsEpkeUo-
   uLJ17oDYeEgHBucRHTnNtHhrE39Pj4');

        //$numbers = array(919384191234,918056377914);
        $sender = 'TXTLCL';
        $message = "Dear student your class schedule for tomorrow '$time'";

        $response = $Textlocal->sendSms($numbers, $message, $sender);
        print_r($response);
        //echo $message;
    }
}


$sql="SELECT   * FROM admin
    WHERE username NOT IN (
    SELECT studentname 
    FROM transcation  
    WHERE MONTH(DATE(date))=MONTH(CURDATE())  
    ) 
    and usertype='student'   ";

$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
If(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $username=$row['username'];
        echo $username;
        $mobile=$row['mobile'];

        $numbers=(explode(" ",$mobile));
        foreach ($numbers as $item) {
            echo $item;
        }

        $Textlocal = new Textlocal(false, false, 'e34FsEpkeUo-
uLJ17oDYeEgHBucRHTnNtHhrE39Pj4');

        $sender = 'TXTLCL';
        $message = "Dear student please pay the fees before due date.  ";

        $response = $Textlocal->sendSms($numbers, $message, $sender);
        print_r($response);

    }
}
```

This is my command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/cpdarmkr/public_html/danceschool/message.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be in your codes, but in your command. Maybe try this command, it might work:

```
* * * * *  /usr/bin/php -q /home/cpdarmkr/public_html/danceschool/message.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me

Use cURL:

```
  */5 * * * * curl --silent http://your-website-url/danceschool/message.php
```